# Why some addons are loaded when server is started in a fresh database?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I created a new database "TEST" and have not installed any additional modules.

Then I opened my eclipse in **DEBUG mode**, and marked breakpoints at `__init__.py` files on following modules:

```
1. product
2. project
3. hr
4. account
```

Why does these addons are loaded even if the module is not Installed in my **"TEST"** database?

Answer (score 0):

The `'auto_install': True` flag within the `__openerp__.py` file means that the module will be automatically installed as soon as all its dependencies are satisfied.

The `'active': True` flag determines the modules that are installed on the database creation.

Modules such as `base` and other base dependencies are installed in to any new database.